# Extra line added :after pseudo-element when using HTML5 DTD (versus XHTML1)

Tags: css, html, xhtml, pseudo-element

For a good long while I've been using a really nice column spanning method I stumbled across, wherein I can have a div with the class `.boxcontainer` and child `.box` elements, and using an `:after` pseudo-element on `.boxcontainer`, my `.box` columns justify nice and evenly across the page. Here are the all-important definitions:

```css
.boxcontainer {
    text-align:                 justify;
    -ms-text-justify:           distribute-all-lines;
    text-justify:               distribute-all-lines;
    background-color:             orange;
}

.boxcontainer:after {
    content:                    '';
    display:                    inline-block;
    width:                      100%;
    height:                     0px;
    font-size:                  0px;
    line-height:                0px;
}
```

Most of my previous projects have been **XHTML1 Transitional** (which I have subsequently learned uses a limited quirks mode when compared to other DTDs), and using this method in XHTML1 the parent `.boxcontainer` always wrapped perfectly flush around the child `.box` elements.

However, working on a new project in HTML5, I've discovered that there appears to be an extra line added underneath the justified `.box` elements. You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/RZQTM/1/ - click on **Fiddle Options** and change the DTD to just about anything else and you'll see what I mean - an orange 'band' appears underneath the justified blue boxes.

I *think* this is down to something in the `:after` pseudo-element being rendered almost like an additional line of content, but I have no idea how to fix it. Any tips on how to remove the extra space under the boxes would be most gratefully received.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick i use to make this extra line to vanish is to apply `line-height:0;` on parent , 
and reset `line-height` to 1.2em or whatever line-hight you had setted.
vertical-align:top;/* or bottom */ on :after elements ends up to swallow any vertical gaps left.

one exemple : http://codepen.io/gcyrillus/pen/dlvCp

Comment: This is a very useful trick especially if you absolutely need very clean mark-up with no extra elements.  Setting an explicit value for the line-height requires some design attention but this is a very minor limitation.

Comment: Having to add only a couple of lines of CSS makes this a winner in my book. Thanks, @GCyrillus.

Answer (score 0):

**A work around with extra markup and using CSS table-cells**

I sometimes use the following.  In the HTML, I add an extra element `div.spacer`:

```
<div class="boxcontainer">
    <div class="box two">
         <h3>This is the title</h3>
            Lorem ipsum dolor amit ...</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="box two">
         <h3>This is the title</h3>
            Lorem ipsum dolor amit ...</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="box two">
         <h3>This is the title</h3>
            Lorem ipsum dolor amit ...</div>
    <div class="spacer"></div>
    <div class="box two">
         <h3>This is the title</h3>
            Lorem ipsum dolor amit ...</div>
</div>
```

For the CSS, I use `display: table` on the parent container and then `display: table-cell` on the `.box` child elements:

```
.boxcontainer {
    background-color: orange;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    font-family: Trebuchet MS;    
}
```

The demo fiddle is: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/xWfk2/

Internally, the CSS re-purposes the  `.spacer` as sibling table-cells and the default spacing tends to be even because the `.box` elements have a fixed width.

This approach is ideal if the `.spacer` elements serve a useful purpose (have real content) and if you have other reasons to use table-cells, say vertical positioning control and so on.